# Variables con processing

Tags: java, variables, booleano

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tenemos cuatro rectángulos de diferentes colores. Queremos que al pulsar cada uno de los  rectángulos del kahoot nos saldrá un mensaje en el centro de la pantalla diciéndonos cuál de ellos estamos pulsando. La letra será del color correspondiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Código? ¿Qué tenéis?

Comment: Te invito a que leas [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Processing es Java, no javascript. Edito las etiquetas